# jQuery AJAX jsonp return response after done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, class, jsonp

Its similar question from here [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

in Ajax JSONP, how do i get the response after done?

https://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/svwxm5tt/

```
class Api {

    constructor() {

    }

    yahoo(query) {

    }

    jsfiddle(query){

        let result = '';

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonp',
            data: {
              query: 'query',
              format: 'json'
            },
        }).done(function(response) {
            result = response;
            console.log(result);
        });

        return result;

    }

}

$api = new Api;

console.log( $api.jsfiddle() ); // empty
```

Answer (score 1):

The `JSONP` "protocol" relies on the site replying to your request with a JavaScript statement of the form,

```
 someFunction( someJSON )
```

> The name of the function is supplied as an argument from your code,
>   with the idea being that the response script, once consumed and
>   interpreted by the browser, will result in a call to that function
>   with a parsed blob of JSON — which is to say, a JavaScript object. The
>   jQuery library will do some of the bookeeping work for you, even to
>   the extent of creating the globally-scoped function to call (which
>   will be code that just calls the callback you supply as the "success"
>   argument).

[Example](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2682)